# javascript objects with child objects - how to use it correctly

Tags: javascript, dictionary, nested

I have seen how in Python there can be a named tuple to store and retreive values associated with a key value, like so:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = {
    0: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=False, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=False),
    1: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=False, LocalityRequired=False, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=True, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    2: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=True, RegionDisplay=False, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    3: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=True, RegionDisplay=False, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    ..........
}
```

I am trying to replicate the above code in javascript. Searching, I found one obscure and not very helpful reference to a javascript "nested dictionary" but I could not find any examples. I have tried searching on other variations, but came up blank. Would this approach be known as a "nested dictionary" or does it go by another name?

I am hoping that someone may be able to shed some light on the topic and have a look at an example of how I suspect this javascript nested dictionary syntax may be set out.

```
var addressNestedDictionary = {
    0: {"LocalityDisplay": 'True', "LocalityRequired": "False", "RegionDisplay": "True", "RegionRequired": "False", "PostcodeDisplay": "True", "PostcodeRequired": "False"}, 
    1: {"LocalityDisplay": "False", "LocalityRequired": "False", "RegionDisplay": "True", "RegionRequired": "True", "PostcodeDisplay": "True", "PostcodeRequired": "True"},
    2: {"LocalityDisplay": "True", "LocalityRequired": "True", "RegionDisplay": "False", "RegionRequired": "False", "PostcodeDisplay": "True", "PostcodeRequired": "True"},
    3: {"LocalityDisplay": "True", "LocalityRequired": "True", "RegionDisplay": "False", "RegionRequired": "False", "PostcodeDisplay": "True", "PostcodeRequired": "True"},
    ........
};
```

If the above approach is correct, how would I call the nested dictionary?

Comment: `addressNestedDictionary[0].LocalityDisplay` or `addressNestedDictionary[0]["LocalityDisplay"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has objects, not dictionaries. You can instantiate an object in two ways:

```
var myObj = {};
var myObj = new Object();
```

Objects allow you to access their named properties. You can set properties during creation:

```
var myObj = {
    0 : "fun",
    test : [1, 2, 3],
    "delete" : "you need to surround keywords, like delete, in quotes",
    "if" : "otherwise, the quotes are optional"
}
```

Or later on:

```
myObj.anArray = [];
```

Object properties can even be another object!

```
myObj.subObject = {};
```

You can access these properties in two ways:

```
myObj["subObject"]    // equal to {}
myObj.subObject       // equal to {}
```

In your case, you would access a child object with:

```
addressNestedDictionary[0]
/* returns
   {
    "LocalityDisplay": 'True',
    "LocalityRequired": "False",
    "RegionDisplay": "True",
    "RegionRequired": "False",
    "PostcodeDisplay": "True", "PostcodeRequired": "False"
   }
*/
```

Note how I used `addressNestedDictionary[0]`. This is because `addressNestedDictionary.0` would be a syntax error—it would be incorrectly parsed. Both notations, bracket and dot, do exactly the same thing otherwise, though.

Comment: Royhowie, Thanks I have the object & child objects working. 

But how do I incorporate the value into an if statement? For example: 

if (addressNestedDictionary[$('#id_address_country_style_type').val()].LocalityDisplay )
    {
        //do something true.
    } else {
        //do something false.
    }

Comment: @user1261774 that should work, although you may want to check for the object's existence first via `nestedAddress[someVal] && nestedAddress[someVal].LocalityDisplay`